# Socket data corruption

Tags: c, sockets

I'm working on a simple socket client, that sends a simple letter "p" to the server, and then reads the response from the server. It is working fully, except for one confusing issue. The very first time the socket is read from (it happens in a loop), the data is garbled and corrupt, with results like "ÿýÿû" and "µÞv". All the data received after the first response is fine and valid.

The code I'm using to receive is:

```
int n;
char buffer[256];
bzero(buffer,256);
strcpy(buffer, "p");
n = write(manSock,buffer,256);
if (n < 0)
{
 error("ERROR writing to management server");
}
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(manSock,buffer,256);
if (n < 0)
{
 error("ERROR reading from management server");
}
return buffer;
```

`manSock` is the socket file descriptor.

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: apart from the buffer, are you returning the length? or have you tried to add the '\0' at the end before printing it? buffer[n] = '\0';

Comment: Is this part of a function?  If so, then returning the address of a local variable `buffer` is *undefined behavior*.  Please edit your post to show that this is indeed a function call that you're posting

Comment: Also, you might want to clarify why you have C++ tag instead of C (just to remove confusion).

Comment: OT: Always compare the result of `read()`/`write()` to how much the function was told to read/write! Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24474150/694576

Comment: Also `read()` and `write()` return `ssize_t` not `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send only upto the length(strlen) of the buffer. Its best practice to always send the length of the buffer before actually sending the data.

```
int len;
len = strlen(buffer);
n = write(manSock,&len , sizeof(int));
if (n < 0)
{
 error("ERROR writing to len management server");
}
n = write(manSock,buffer,strlen(buffer));
if (n < 0)
{
 error("ERROR writing to management server");
}
bzero(buffer,256);
n = read(manSock,&len,sizeof(int));
if (n < 0)
{
  error("ERROR reading len from management server");
}
n = read(manSock,buffer,len);
if (n < 0)
{
  error("ERROR reading from management server");
}
```

Comment: "*Its best practice to always send the length of the buffer before actually sending the data*" this is only one possibility out of various how to apply an application level protocol. Another would be to terminate each "message" send by a terminator (e.g.`'\0'`  or `'\n'` or `\r\n'` or ...) and have the receiving side read up until this terminator is found.

Comment: In future, if you wish to change the send multiple strings sending length will help to parse the multi strings. You can also use other encoding type like UTF-8, UTF-16 without changing the application protocol. Protocol is also secure since it won't cause buffer overflow problems even if there is no NULL termination.

Comment: "*... it won't cause buffer overflow problems*" this highly depends on the way it is implemented. ;-) I however did not want to express your proposal of an application level protocol would be bad, useless or wrong in any case ... - I just wanted to mention that there are mutliple other ways to do it. Which one to go highly depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be a problem related to sockets, but to memory management.

You seem to return a pointer to memory being valid only local to the function.

Assuming your "real" code looks like this

```
char * foo(void)
{
  char buffer[256];

  /* read into buffer */

  return buffer;
}

void bar (void)
{
  char * p = foo();
  printf("%s\n", p);
}
```

then `p` refers to invalid memory after `foo()` returned, as buffer had been implicitly deallocated upon `foo()`'s return.

To fix this

- either allocate `buffer` dynamical in `foo()` using [`malloc()`, `calloc()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) or [`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html)

  ```
  char * foo(void)
  {
    char * buffer = malloc(256);
    memset(buffer, 0, 256);
    /* read into buffer */
    return buffer;
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  char * foo(void)
  {
    char * buffer = calloc(256, sizeof(*buffer));
    /* read into buffer */
    return buffer;
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  char * foo(void)
  {
    char buffer[256] = {0};
    /* read into buffer */
    return strdup(buffer);
  }
  ```
- or pass down to `foo()` a reference to a buffer being allocated in `bar()` (or higher).

  ```
  void foo(char * buffer)
  {
     /* read into where buffer points */
  }

  void bar(void)
  {
    char buffer[256] = {0};
    foo(buffer);
    /* print buffer */
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your code as it stands now (assuming it is a function) is bad, even if you took the advice given in the other answers and comments concerning the `write` and `read` functions.

The reason is that you're returning a locally defined array (actually the address of the first element), `buffer`, and doing so is *undefined behavior*.  So if you're retrieving the return value, `buffer` is no longer valid and could conceivably contain garbage data, even if you filled it with valid data within the function.

The C++ tag was removed, but if you really are using C++, you could always copy the results to a `std::string` and return that instead:

```
std::string someFunc()
{
    int n;
    char buffer[256];
    //.. your code goes here
    //...
    return std::string(buffer, len); // where len is the number of characters read
}
```

If you're using C, then have the user pass you the buffer and you fill it in within the function.  Don't create local arrays and return them -- that's the bottom line.

Answer (score 0):

You've designed your API completely incorrectly

1. You're returning the address of a local buffer, which won't exist and may be overwritten after the call.
2. You're throwing away the length returned by recv(), so the caller has no way of knowing how much of the buffer is valid, even if you fixed (1) somehow.

You need the *caller* to supply the buffer, and you need to return the *length.* This makes your method signature look remarkably like that of recv(). In Other words you possibly don't really need this method at all. The caller could just call recv().