# Write n bytes and read n bytes: sending number of bytes to read using uint16_t

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, stdint

I've been using these [read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149925/7158454) and [write](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24260280/694576) functions (provided by @alk).
The problem is that I don't know how to correctly send the `uint16_t data_size;`.
Here is my actual code to send a general example buffer:

```
uint16_t data_size;
int retry_on_interrupt = 0;
char buffer[] = "Hello world!";
data_size = (uint16_t) sizeof(buffer);    

/* sending data_size */
writen(socket, data_size, 2, retry_on_interrupt);

/* sending buffer */
writen(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer);
```

And here is my actual code to receive a general example buffer:

```
/* receiving data_size */
readn(socket, &data_size, 2);

/* receiving buffer */
readn(socket, buffer, data_size);
```

But this is not working, I think because `writen` requires a `const char *`, instead I'm using a `uint16_t`...
How should these calls be? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
writen(socket, data_size, 2, retry_on_interrupt);
```

by

```
if (-1 == writen(socket, &data_size, sizeof data_size, 1))
{
   perror("writen() failed writing size");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

and replace this line

```
writen(socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer);
```

by

```
if (-1 == writen(socket, buffer, data_size, 1))
{
   perror("writen() failed writing pay-load");
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

---

You definitely want to add error-checking to the reading functions as well!

---

Also you want to take care of a possible [endianness (byte-order)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) issue, when sending/receiving between to different hardware-platforms.

Comment: Ok @alk now it's all clear and it all got working. The problem was with a sendfile call. I had to clean `offset` and re-initialize it to `0`. Nothing that had to do with this question, but I wanted to tell you it anyway!